# Simple SPARQL Query on DBpedia

Tags: rdf, sparql, dbpedia

I'm trying a few SPARQL queries on DBPedia RDF files. Sometimes it works but the following query returns an empty result set.

```
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT * WHERE {
    <http://de.dbpedia.org/resource/Algerien> 
    <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/topLevelDomain> ?o .
}
```

I've tested it here: at the [DBpedia SPARQL endpoint](http://dbpedia.org/sparql) and with my local 4store system where I can see that the correct triple is there. What is wrong with my query? Why is not the correct TLD the answer?

Thanks @all

Answer (score 2):

Try it at `http://de.dbpedia.org/sparql`.

You asking for `http://de.dbpedia.org/resource/Algerien` in the German part of dbpedia.

You tried in the English part.